# Draw Spiral in reverse direction(continuous manner) from end point to center?

Tags: turbo-c++, spiral, bgi

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>

void main(){
    int gd=DETECT,gm,i;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"..\\bgi");
    for(i=0;i<1000&&!kbhit();i++){

        arc(getmaxx()/2,getmaxy()/2,0+i,90+i,i/10);
        delay(10);
    }
    getch();

}
```

When i try to start i=1000 to 0 and starting point as i and end point is i-90 nothing happens..

Comment: Does this compile without error? What do you expect the line `int gd=DETECT,gm,i;` to do?

Comment: What are you using as a compiler and terminal emulator? A lot of the modern stuff, pretty much all of it actually, won't do bgi.

Comment: If this code is working and some other code is not working, post the other code as well. (Don't describe it, show it.)

Comment: i ran it turbo c++ and its working perfectly....but it start from center...but need it from end to center...

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>

void main(){
 int gd=DETECT,gm,i;
 initgraph(&gd,&gm,"..\\bgi");
 for(i=1000;i<=0&&!kbhit();i--){
  
  arc(getmaxx()/2,getmaxy()/2,i,i-90,i/10);
  delay(10);
 }
 getch();
 
}

Comment: Please, don't use comments to post additional code. Please, use [edit] instead and improve your question.

Comment: Why would you tag the question with `c++` when it has absolutely nothing related to it? And as @Scheff has told, make changes to the code in the question if you wish to do so, instead of adding them as comments. Not everyone will see what changes you have made.

Comment: Pay close attention to your comparison operators.

Comment: A note: You are learning a pre-Standardization version of C++ that was all but abandoned more than 20 years ago. If this is for school do, what you need to to to pass your courses, but I strongly recommend supplementing your education [with some books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on and practice of modern C++. It will smooth your entry into the workforce. If this is not for school and you can select the tools you wish to learn, grab an up-to-date copy of clang, GCC or Visual Studio and a few good books and start learning the new stuff.